# C++ error in template function call: type name is not allowed

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Diab compiler complains in line @@@ that type name is not allowed.

```
template<
    Task TASK,
    Event EVENT>
class TManager :
    public AbstractTManager,
    public common::ITManager
{
    public:
    typedef os::EManager<TASK>  tEManager;

    TManager()
    { /* ... */}

    virtual void init()
    {

        tEManager::registerCallback<
            EVENT,
            TManager, /* @@@ */
            &TManager::func>(*this);
    }

    void func()
    { /* ... */}
}
```

In EManager registerCallback is defined in following way:

```
template<TType task>
class EManager
{
public:
    template<
        EType event,
        typename e_listener,
        void (e_listener::*TMethod)()
        >
    static void registerCallback(e_listener& listener)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

The second template argument is e_listener with keyword typename so I don't know why it reports problem. Did I miss something?
Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords. The error would fit if the compiler is treating `tEManager` as a value, `<` as less than, and `EVENT` as the other operand, with `TManager` then being the second operand of a comma operator.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `template`:

```
tEManager::template registerCallback<
        EVENT,
        TManager,
        &TManager::func>(*this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Jarod42 and chris. It works! I missed this really valuable topic which includes solution in chapter "The template keyword":
[Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)